# Using optional namespaces results in errors when using Gnosis Safe

Tags: gnosis-safe, walletconnect

We're using Gnosis Safe via Wallet Connect 2 and we're getting different errors after establishing the session with optional namespaces.

The session IS indeed established just fine after connecting the wallet. We're getting the errors below when trying to create the safe. We're not receiving any events from Gnosis, no transactions to sign. These errors pop up in the top right corner of the web page.

If we don't pass any optional namespaces then it's working just fine, we get the request to sign the transaction and the flow goes on.

Other DApps do work when optional namespaces are present in session connection request.

```
cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT ] (error={"code":-32000,"message":"gas required exceeds allowance (0)"}, method="estimateGas", transaction={"from":"0xE747f56CCf4f0A800CAaF5533FddAc776Ad14996","maxPriorityFeePerGas":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x59682f00"},"maxFeePerGas":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x0f79aa89c4"},"to":"0xa6B71E26C5e0845f74c812102Ca7114b6a896AB2","data":"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","accessList":null}, code=UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT, version=providers/5.7.2)
```

or

```
fee cap less than block base fee: address 0xeEE27662c2B8EBa3CD936A23F039F3189633e4C8, gasFeeCap: 63755909170 baseFee: 123855893013
```

or

```
insufficient funds for intrinsic transaction cost [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-INSUFFICIENT_FUNDS ] (error={"code":-32000,"message":"insufficient funds for gas * price + value: address 0xeEE27662c2B8EBa3CD936A23F039F3189633e4C8 have 0 want 39915389360400000000"}, method="estimateGas", transaction={"from":"0xeEE27662c2B8EBa3CD936A23F039F3189633e4C8","maxPriorityFeePerGas":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x59682f00"},"maxFeePerGas":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x0f7d3cd826"},"to":"0xa6B71E26C5e0845f74c812102Ca7114b6a896AB2","data":"0x1688f0b9000000000000000000000000d9db270c1b5e3bd161e8c8503c55ceabee709552000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000189fed54bb70000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000164b63e800d0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000140000000000000000000000000f48f2b2d2a534e402487b3ee7c18c33aec0fe5e40000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000eee27662c2b8eba3cd936a23f039f3189633e4c8000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000","accessList":null}, code=INSUFFICIENT_FUNDS, version=providers/5.7.2)
```